# TCP packets not reaching app, iptables dropping?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

We are occasionally, but not consistently, experiencing a weird network stack issue. Rebooting the server in question clears it up.

**It happens as follows (gleaned through `tcpdump` on the server)**:

- HTTP client starts sending request to Nginx.
- Server responds normally, acking every packet it gets.
- On the *final* client send, the packet never reaches the receiving socket on the server.
- The client resends the packet several times, then the server finally times out and disconnects.

Also, `strace` of Nginx confirms that the data is *not* reaching Nginx.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/atombender/8e96b8b7fce1694e78d6) is an edited version of the `tcpdump` output. I have simplified the exchange and anonymized some details.

Turning on iptables logging shows some packets being blocked, which may be relevant:

```
IN= OUT=lo SRC=client DST=server LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=39670 DPT=80 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0 
IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=server DST=client LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=39669 WINDOW=31 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
```

However, our iptables setup is pedestrian. We block everything except `RELATED,ESTABLISHED`, and we allow the port in question, 80. I don't see why iptables is blocking this, unless the packets are somehow falling outside the states of `RELATED` and `ESTABLISHED`.

I have also included our `sysctl` settings in the above gist. Anything else I can look at?

Linux 3.8.0 on Ubuntu 12.04.3, on DigitalOcean.

---

**Edit 3**: Disabled iptables, same problem, so it's not caused by bad iptables rules.

---

**Edit 2**: Above I show iptables blocking `RST` packets, but more importantly it's blocking a lot of `ACK`s. I just picked a random log entry, `ACK` seems more common.

---

**Edit 1**: I added iptables tracing. This seems to the part that drops a packet (though, again, not sure if this is related to my problem):

```
TRACE: raw:OUTPUT:rule:2 IN= OUT=lo SRC=client DST=server LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=41572 DPT=8001 SEQ=2118637628 ACK=0 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0 
TRACE: raw:OUTPUT:policy:3 IN= OUT=lo SRC=client DST=server LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=41572 DPT=8001 SEQ=2118637628 ACK=0 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0 
TRACE: filter:OUTPUT:rule:3 IN= OUT=lo SRC=client DST=server LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=41572 DPT=8001 SEQ=2118637628 ACK=0 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0 
TRACE: filter:block:rule:1 IN= OUT=lo SRC=client DST=server LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=41572 DPT=8001 SEQ=2118637628 ACK=0 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0 
TRACE: filter:logging:rule:1 IN= OUT=lo SRC=client DST=server LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=41572 DPT=8001 SEQ=2118637628 ACK=0 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0 
iptables: reject: IN= OUT=lo SRC=client DST=server LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=41572 DPT=8001 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
```

No idea why `lo` is involved here. Server is accepting traffic on `eth0`.

Comment: Your tcpdump output is showing a connection using port 80 while the iptables log is blocking packets to/from port 8001. Is this because the connection has been "anonymized" or is the connection to port 8001 rather unrelated because it would be connecting to a different service altogether?

Comment: My apologies, I was testing with port 80 first, then later moving to 8001 to try to isolate the problem from other services. Both are correct, but I'll update the iptables log output.

Answer (score 1):

Your log definitely shows communication happening on the `lo` interface.

1. Disable `iptables` by changing `INPUT` table default policy to `ACCEPT` and deactivate any `REJECT` or `DROP` rule which might stand in the way
2. Test again and check that it works. If not, the problem comes from somewhere else

I would bet $1000 on the fact your filtering rules accepting traffic are bound to some `eth0` interface, thus rejecting traffic incoming on `lo`.

I would pay attention to where the testing client in relation to the server. If you are running your test client on the same machine, it most probably either uses the `127.0.0.1` IP address or the `localhost` domain name which usually resolves to the same IP address.

That will send traffic on the special loopback interface (`lo`) and not on the `eth0` one.

Unless you bound nginx to a specific interface by asking it to listen on its IP address, nginx will listen by default on `0.0.0.0`, which is every interface. Thus, you won't notice if it accepts connections on `lo` or not. You could try to force nginx listening on your `eth0` IP address just to be sure.

When locally testing your server, ensure you use your one of your external interfaces (`eth[0..]`) IP address, or a domain name resolving to one of them.

Comment: Actually, as I described earlier, clearing iptables (and setting all policies to `ACCEPT`) did nothing. I honestly think this was a fluke on Digital Ocean's networks. Haven't seen it since the last reboot, right after I posted the question.

Comment: I would guess it has more to do with your reboot than with DigitalOcean network, though this probability is not 0... ;o)
Maybe something wreaked havoc in your system and (re)starting/reloading process/configuration helped the problem to naturally solve.

No that, by default, `iptables` rules are not saved on network service stop, thus restarting your machine could simply have unloaded them. :o)

Wild guesses and pure accumption, of course, but I would strongly encourage you to dig further to find the source of that problem. In the meantime, glad to know everything works again!

Comment: Well, each time we rebooted the problem eventually came back, without any changes to iptables. Could be a kernel bug, of course.